# Session vs ssl session

Tags: java, ssl, web

I'm trying to understand session and want to understand the following:

What is the difference between a http session and a SSL session?

Under what circumstances are they created?

Comment: When using SSL in a web context you're talking about https in most cases. Thus a "SSL" session is basically the same as a "http" session - you just might have two sessions depending on whether you're accessing a URL via http or https (e.g. a cookie could have a "secureOnly" flag which would mean it's only transferred via https and if you use that cookie to store the session id you only use that session when using https).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If no session exist, Is a SSL session created by the container (ie tomcat) automatically when moving from http to https assuming no servlet call request.getSession()?

Comment: That might depend on the configuration (I don't know Tomcat too well).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A HTTP session exists if the same client and server have a conversation spanning multiple requests and responses. During this conversation they maintain a state, like that a specific user is logged in or similar. This state is usually maintained with the help of a cookie which gets exchanged all the time.

A SSL/TLS session is similar, only that it is not at the HTTP level and the state does not reflect a logged in user. Instead the state of a TLS session includes the encryption key and the cipher used etc. This state is reflected in a similar way as in HTTP: where you have the cookie in HTTP you have in TLS the session token or the session id.

In HTTP a session is often used to keep the authorized state, i.e. that the user logs in once and can do multiple actions while staying logged in. Thus it is used to reduce the overhead of logging in again and again. In SSL/TLS the session is created for a similar reason: to reduce the overhead of the TLS handshake. If no TLS session exists  a  full handshake will be done. In this handshake the server will proof the identity by sending the certificate and ciphers and key will be exchanged. If instead a session gets reused a less expensive shorter handshake will be done because client and server just continue with the same key and cipher and the proof of identity is still valid.

SSL/TLS session and HTTP session are independent, i.e. there can be overlap or there can be no overlap but it does not matter at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so when a web app moves from http to https, a http session is still used to maintain login state and etc? And if I don't create a session in a servlet or jsp, the user will have to login to every secure page?

Comment: HTTPS is just HTTP over TLS. Unless your code was explicitly designed to work only with plain HTTP  you don't need to do anything to keep using HTTP session with HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just a final question. My understanding now is that when you move from http to https, http session are still used to maintain login state and etc. SSL session are not used for this purpose. Is this correct?

Comment: @DannyR: correct. The application state is only kept by HTTP sessions. TLS session are only use to keep the state of the underlying encryption layer (i.e. TLS).